# How to efficiently import rows from SQL Server to SQL Server CE on mobile device using .net?

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce

How to efficiently do the job?

I have thought about following solutions:

1. Serialize & compress collection -> send to mobile device deserialize and insert to SQL Server CE:

   Problems:
   For a lot of records, such amount of data cannot be deserialized due to memory constraints (Out of memory occurs). because of that lot of records needs to be imported in seperate service calls ...
2. Create on the fly an sqlce temp db with the data to import -> then send it using web service streaming to mobile device, connect to downloaded db file and insert records to the right db.

   This would give me one call and probably would avoid memory limitations ...
3. Are there other better ways of data to transport between SQL Server and SQL Server CE?

Thanks

Comment: Could you use synchronization?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726121

Comment: I looked at that but I am rather looking for another solution...

Comment: 2 is your best option if you cannot use Sync, but keep in mind to create the sdf file on a Serbver 2003 system if you use Windows Mobile 6.x